# Test to check if a function didn't run?

Tags: unit-testing, go

So I'm new to testing in general and I'm stuck trying to write a test for a function that triggers another function. This is what I have so far but it's kind of backwards and blocks forever if the function doesn't run:

```
var cha = make(chan bool, 1)                

func TestFd(t *testing.T) {                 
  c := &fd.Fdcount{Interval: 1, MaxFiles: 1}
  c.Start(trigger)
  if <- cha {                               

  }                                         
}                                           

func trigger(i int) {                       
  cha <- true                               
}
```

`c.Start` will trigger the `trigger()` function when certain criteria is met. It tests whether or not the criteria is met every `1` second.

The error case is when the function fails to run. Is there a way to test for this or is there a way to use the testing package to test for success (e.g. `t.Pass()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `c.Start` is synchronous, you can simply pass a function that sets a value in the test case's scope, and then test against that value. Condider the `functionCalled` variable in the example below that is set by the `trigger` function ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gwNg8qAThh)):

```
func TestFd(t *testing.T) {
    functionCalled := false
    trigger := func(i int) {
        functionCalled = true;
    }

    c := &fd.Fdcount{Interval: 1, MaxFiles: 1}
    c.Start(trigger)

    if !functionCalled {
        t.FatalF("function was not called")
    }
}
```

If `c.Start` is asynchronous, you can use a `select` statement to implement a timeout that will fail the test when the passed function was not called within a given time frame ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IWuC4hKTDW)):

```
func TestFd(t *testing.T) {
    functionCalled := make(chan bool)
    timeoutSeconds := 1 * time.Second
    trigger := func(i int) {
        functionCalled <- true
    }

    timeout := time.After(timeoutSeconds)

    c := &SomeStruct{}
    c.Start(trigger)

    select {
        case <- functionCalled:
            t.Logf("function was called")
        case <- timeout:
            t.Fatalf("function was not called within timeout")
    }
}
```